# How optimal UDP communication should work? (ephemeral port)

Tags: sockets, udp

Hello i just facing problem with two-side communication based on UDP. Current solution working like this:

Side A:

- independent socket a1 listening on port X
- independent socket a2 used for requesting to side B and port X

Side B:

- basically black box (but probably similar)

So far it worked like this: to send request just send packet throught socket.a2:X and than receive packet from independent socket.a1:X (ports are same).

After side B update it stopped working.

I know that for TCP its one side listener and when it accepts connection, it opens another socket on random ephemeral port and keep communication there (details are managed by os).

Is there similar mechanism for UDP? Its better way to use one socket for sending and listening? I see in tcpdump UDP packets, which now have destination to random ports instead of port X.

I tried to use one socket and cant get it working (tried even to connect and listen on local endpoint - not working).

Thanks for some clarification.

(there are no firewall or routing problems for sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of "listening" in UDP, only binding to a port and then sending and/or receiving packets.  Therefore calling `listen()` or `accept()` on a UDP socket is an error, and will not accomplish anything useful.

There is (barely) a concept of "connecting" in UDP, but `connect()` on a UDP socket doesn't do anything other than set the default destination-address (and a packet-source-filter) for the `send()` and `recv()` calls (respectively) when they are used with that socket, so that you can use those functions with the UDP socket rather than always calling `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`.  In practice, though, I'd recommend not using `connect()` with a UDP socket, since the advantage of being able to supply one less argument to `send()` and `recv()` is outweighed by the fact that a UDP socket that has had `connect()` called on it will only be able to receive incoming packets from a single source-IP-address-and-port.

It's quite possible (and arguably preferable) to use a single UDP socket for both sending and receiving; just `bind()` it to a port and then call `sendto()` and/or `recvfrom()` on it.  You can even use that single UDP socket to send to multiple destinations and receive from multiple sources if you want.  Note that you might find it useful to set the UDP socket to non-blocking and use `select()` or `poll()` or similar as your wait-for-I/O-ready function, since when using the default (blocking) I/O style, it's easy to end up with your I/O thread stuck inside a `recvfrom()` for a long time, when you want to `sendto()` a packet.

Comment: Thanks for comment. My previous debug tests was not right - i still sent requests from separated socket. Now i see in tcpdump when i send request from listener socket (by sendto) the source port and destination is same (not the ephemeral random one). Dunno if it helps - the testing service is down now.

Comment: Tested now and it works. When it use one socket it keeps source+dest ports - listener port is bound to destination and packets have source port as the listener port.